# Meteor Galaxy logging in on Primary vs custom domain

Tags: meteor, authentication, deployment

I have Meteor deployed on Galaxy using both the primary domain and a custom domain but when I log into the primary domain, then try to access my app from the custom domain I have to log in again.

Is their a way to log into both instead of having to do it separately?

Answer (score 0):

No. Login works by storing your Meteor login token in local storage and this is not shared between domains (or even subdomains).

Comment: Thanks @Eliezer Steinbock. Is there a way to switch domains so my custom domain is the primary one?  I couldn't see how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean primary? It's up to you what you consider primary